# Is there a way to debug findbugs filters?

Tags: maven, findbugs

I'm using FindBugs and FindBugs Contrib to do some static analysis on my Java code.  There are some "bugs" I'd like to filter in my Findbugs report.  So I created a findbugs-exclude.xml file and wrote the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Class name="com.masked.out.for.stack.Overflow" />
        <Method name="myMethod" />
        <Bug pattern="DRE_DECLARED_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION" />
    </Match>
    <Match>
        <Class name="com.some.other.class.Name" />
        <Method name="getSomeProperty" />
        <Bug pattern="EI_EXPOSE_REP" />
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

My report now excludes the EI_EXPOSE_REP bug, but not the DRE_DECLARED_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION bug.  Any hints on how I can debug this?  The class name and method names are correct.  I copied them right out of the report and pasted them in this file.

Comment: Please try `mvn -X ....` for debugging.

Comment: Please post your pom.xml (findbugs configuration segment)

Comment: @h3xStream I'm sorry, I will not be able to post my pom.xml as it is proprietary to my employer (hence why I anonymized my findbugs-exclude.xml file).

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk
I'll try the -X and see if any interesting output is produced.  Thanks.

Comment: @JasonThompson : My though was that the file containing the filters is not properly specify in the pom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was not getting bugs to show up was due to not having the maven plugin configured correctly.  If anyone else is struggling to filter bugs, verify that the excludeFilterFile tag is in the plugin configuration and that it's pointing to a valid file.